# Centering the page number in the rotated page

Tags: fancyhdr, pdflscape

My issue is related to the common problem of rotating the page. I used the pdflscape package to rotate my page but the page number stayed the same. I used/found this block of code to create a new page style:

```
\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
\fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
\fancyfoot{% Footer
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Right
  \rlap{\hspace{.75cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
    \smash{% Remove vertical height
      \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}}% Rotate counter-clockwise
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

This is working just fine but I cannot centering the page number and it looks bolder compared to other page numbers in my page class, which is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
```

I am kind of new to latex and having difficulties understanding that code block so I cannot change it in the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in your example (like 4.87in) depend on the page size, margins, etc. So you would have to experiment, or better, do a proper calculation.

In the meantime, here is a different approach to having a page in landscape, which doesn't use `pdflscape`, but does have the correct headers and footers also in landscape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Save papersize and text size
\newlength\mypagewidth
\newlength\mypageheight
\newlength\mytextwidth
\newlength\mytextheight

% Luatex doesn't have \pdfpagewidth/\pdfpageheight, but
% uses \pagewidth/pageheight instead. So we check if \pdf... are available,
% if not, use alias them to \pagewidth/pageheight.
\ifdefined\pdfpagewidth\else
  \let\pdfpagewidth\pagewidth\let\pdfpageheight\pageheight
\fi

\AtBeginDocument{% after the geometry has really been set
% Officially should use \setlength, just being lazy.
\setlength\mypagewidth{\pdfpagewidth}%
\setlength\mypageheight{\pdfpageheight}%
\setlength\mytextwidth{\textwidth}%
\setlength\mytextheight{\textheight}%
}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Thickness
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Thickness
\fancyhead[L]{Test Header}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhfoffset{0pt}% this makes \headwidth follow \textwidth

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
Page 1

\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\pdfpagewidth=\mypageheight \pdfpageheight=\mypagewidth
\newgeometry{textwidth=\mytextheight, textheight=\mytextwidth,top=25mm,left=25mm}
\section{Section 2}
Page 2

\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\pdfpagewidth=\mypagewidth \pdfpageheight=\mypageheight
\newgeometry{margin=25mm}
\section{Section 3}
Page 3

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```